# How can I find all companies that have branch in all cities of another company

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I use SQL server 2014. I have a table like this:

```
CREATE Table Comp
(
  ID int identity(1,1),
  City varchar(50),
  Name varchar(50)
)
```

I have these record in my table

```
INSERT INTO Comp
values 
  ('Montreal','ABC'),
  ('QuebecCity','ABC'),
  ('Mont-tremblant','ABC'),
  ('Saint-donant','ABC'),
  ('Saint-savaure','ABC'),

  ('Montreal','QQQ'),
  ('QuebecCity','QQQ'),
  ('Mont-tremblant','QQQ'),
  ('Saint-donant','QQQ'),
  ('Saint-savaure','QQQ'),

  ('Montreal','www'),
  ('QuebecCity','www'),
  ('Mont-tremblant','www'),

  ('Montreal','dd'),
  ('QuebecCity','dd'),
  ('Mont-tremblant','dd'),
  ('Saint-donant','dd'),
  ('Saint-savaure','dd'),  
  ('trois rivieres','dd'),
  ('perce','dd'),

  ('City1','SSS'),
  ('City2','SSS'),
  ('City3','SSS'),
  ('City4','SSS'),
  ('Saint-savaure','SSS'),  
  ('City6','SSS'),
  ('City7','dd')
```

How can I query just the company's name which has the cites in all of the cites in other Company

For example if my master Company is 'ABC', It should query 'QQQ' and 'dd'

Comment: Shouldn't the master company also query 'www'?

Comment: Yes, In our query we can have any company as master company. It will be sent like condition to our query

Comment: I mean in your example, where master company is 'ABC', and your records are as you stated shouldn't it return 'QQQ', 'dd'. AND **'www'**?

Comment: No. 'www' company has not all of the city that 'abc' company has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   comp c1
WHERE  City IN (SELECT city
                FROM   comp
                WHERE  NAME = 'ABC')
       AND NAME <> 'ABC'
GROUP  BY NAME
HAVING Count(DISTINCT City) = (SELECT Count(DISTINCT city)
                               FROM   comp
                               WHERE  NAME = 'ABC')
```

If you don't have *duplicate* `city` for each `name` then a better approach

```
SELECT c1.NAME
FROM   comp c1
       JOIN (SELECT city,
                    Count(1)OVER() AS cnt
             FROM   comp
             WHERE  NAME = 'ABC') c2
         ON c1.City = c2.City
WHERE  c1.NAME <> 'ABC'
GROUP  BY c1.NAME
HAVING Count(c1.city) = Max(cnt)
```

Comment: I have verified your first query with my query in my answer and I have found that your query is 100 times faster than mine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
declare @selectedcompany nvarchar(10) = 'abc'

select distinct name
from comp rsDistinct
where not exists
(
    select city from comp where name = @selectedcompany
    except
    select city from comp where name = rsDistinct.name
)
and name != 'ABC'
```

Comment: you have to change the place of your select inside your where clause and add this part also : And rsDistinct.name <> 'ABC'

Answer (score 0):

During this time, I have written this query also :

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
  S.name  
FROM Comp AS S 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (   
        (
            SELECT 
              city 
            FROM Comp 
            WHERE name = 'ABC'
        ) 
        EXCEPT 
        (   SELECT 
            T.city 
            FROM Comp AS T 
            WHERE  T.name = S.Name 
        )
    )
    AND S.name <> 'ABC'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is Query 1 below.

I have also tested your query (Query 2) and tried to find out which of the two is more efficient based on 'Actual Execution Plan' and the result is as under:

Query 1: query cost (relative to batch) : 25%

```
select Name, COUNT(*) as cities 
from (select city from Comp where name = 'ABC') m
join (select name, city from Comp where Name <> 'ABC') c on m.city = c.city 
group by Name
having COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from Comp where Name = 'ABC')
```

Query 2: query cost (relative to batch) : 75%

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.name  
FROM Comp AS S 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(   
    (SELECT city FROM Comp WHERE name = 'ABC') 
    EXCEPT 
    (SELECT T.city FROM Comp AS T WHERE  T.name = S.Name 
    )
)
AND S.name <> 'ABC'
```

**NOTE:** On later evaluation, I found solution by @Prdp is more efficient.

For duplicate city scenario

```
select Name
from (select city from Comp where name = 'ABC') m
join (select name, city from Comp where Name <> 'ABC') c on m.city = c.city 
group by Name
having COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT c.City) = (select COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT City) from Comp where Name = 'ABC')
```

Comment: I have run this command about 14 times for having more than 3,000,000 recorde in Comp table : 
INSERT INTO Comp (city,name)
  Select city,name From Comp   ; 
after that your query has this error : 
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: If you replace Count with count_big the problem will be fix but the result will be null

Comment: If we have duplicate city for one city, It dosen't work.

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi, query modified for duplicate city case.

Comment: What about 3,000,000 record?